# Roland PHA-4 keybed -- what is the octave width?

Tags: digital-piano

*One of Roland's keybed is PHA-4, used for example in FP-E50 or Fantom 08 keyboards/digital pianos.*

I didn't find it in specification, thus my question -- what is the octave width in this keybed?

*Octave width -- the distance/width from key X, for example C4, to the same key but octave higher, in this example C5.*

Comment: Might be a good question for the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an 88-note weighted keyboard, designed to emulate a piano keyboard. It's inconceivable that such a keyboard would have 'mini keys'.   So the octave width will be 165mm, same as every other modern piano.

Comment: 160 mm is not that unusual, for example Yamaha CK series AFAIK has such width. So there is a difference between "it has" and "it  will have". But of course it could be 165 mm, but I am asking to be sure, not to guess.

Comment: The question is a good one, because, sadly, there is no real standard on keyboard width.  Especially electronic keyboards may vary by as much as 20-30 mm from one end of the keyboard to another, making  vertical alignment of stacked keyboards by different vendors problematic.

Indeed, there is a niche market of custom narrow-gage piano keyboard replacements for small-handed keyboard players (like myself).

Comment: I'd be unhappy to have to play a keyboard with just-slightly-narrower-than-standard keys, I have to say...